# Is the worship of white Shivalinga forbidden at home?

Tags: shiva, worship, shiva-lingam

I recently got myself a Shwet (white) Shivalinga. But I read somewhere on the Internet that worshipping of shwet shivalinga is only permissible at shamsaan and not at home. Is it true? If false is there any particular process of worshipping the linga?

Comment: I have also been told that white Shiva Lingas mustn't be kept in homes.

Comment: I do not know what the scriptures say. I would love to know. But one of our extended family members got a white Shiva linga from someone and placed it in their home. He died after a couple of days. Within a year, his wife also died. Now, their teenage daughter is an orphan. One astrologer came and told us not to keep the white Shiva linga at home. The daughter then removed it.

Comment: read this english news article which says white shivling appeared in a place in Bengal. But, no priest wants to take it home. One guy took it at home. But returned within 48 hours. https://www.news18.com/india/mysterious-white-shivalinga-emerges-in-bengal-but-cant-be-worshipped-heres-why-7535893.html

Comment: One of our local priests said white shiva lingas are worshipped on cremation grounds. You can find it there. It is not meant to be worshipped by householders.